# Junit test - No errors that I can see?

Tags: java, junit

I was trying to use Junit test for a method, but the test failed although the "expected" was the same as the "was....". I'm wondering what is the problem?
lowerRate method is just a method which takes as input a "HotelRoom" and outputs the price at a 10% discount. Thanks
This is my code for the test:

```
@Test
public void testLowerRate() {
    System.out.println("lowerRate");
    HotelRoom room = new HotelRoom(4, 300, "N");
    HotelRoom instance = new HotelRoom(0, 0, "N");
    HotelRoom expResult = new HotelRoom(4, 270, "N");
    HotelRoom result = instance.lowerRate(room);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public void testLowerRate2() {
    System.out.println("lowerRate");
    HotelRoom room = new HotelRoom(4, 100, "N");
    HotelRoom instance = new HotelRoom(0, 0, "N");
    HotelRoom expResult = new HotelRoom(4, 90, "N");
    HotelRoom result = instance.lowerRate(room);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
@Test
public void testLowerRate3() {
    System.out.println("lowerRate");
    HotelRoom room = new HotelRoom(4, 1000, "N");
    HotelRoom instance = new HotelRoom(0, 0, "N");
    HotelRoom expResult = new HotelRoom(4, 900, "N");
    HotelRoom result = instance.lowerRate(room);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
}
```

EDIT ------

Here is the code for the program:

```
class HotelRoom {

private int numofBeds;
private double rateperNight;
private String YorNoceanView;

HotelRoom(int input1, double input2, String input3) {
    numofBeds = input1;
    rateperNight = input2;
    YorNoceanView = input3;

}

public int getnumofBeds() {
    return numofBeds;
}

public void setnumofBeds(int numofBeds) {
    this.numofBeds = numofBeds;
}

public double getrateperNight() {
    return rateperNight;
}

public void setrateperNight(double rate) {
    this.rateperNight = rateperNight;
}

public String getYorNoceanView() {
    return YorNoceanView;
}

public void setYorNoceanView(String YorNoceanView) {
    this.YorNoceanView = YorNoceanView;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hotel Room{" + "Title= " + numofBeds + ", Rate per night= $" + rateperNight + ", Ocean View (Y or N)=" + YorNoceanView + "}";

}

String roomUnder(HotelRoom room, double price) {
    if (room.getrateperNight() > price) {
        return "The room costs more than the given price";
    }
    if (room.getrateperNight() < price) {
        return "The room costs less than the given price";
    }
    else 
        return "The room costs as much as the given price.";
}
HotelRoom lowerRate(HotelRoom room) {
    room.rateperNight = 0.9 * room.rateperNight;
    return room;
}
}

public class Chpt2930HotelRoom {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    String input = "input";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of Beds: ");
    int nextLineBeds = scan.nextInt();
    HotelRoom HotelR = new HotelRoom(num1, num2, input);
    HotelR.setnumofBeds(nextLineBeds);
    System.out.println();


    System.out.print("Enter rate per night in Dollars: $");
    double nextLineRate = scan.nextDouble();
    HotelR.setrateperNight(nextLineRate);
    System.out.println();


    System.out.print("Enter whether the room has an ocean view (Y or N): ");
    String nextLineOcean = user.nextLine();
    HotelR.setYorNoceanView(nextLineOcean);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(HotelR.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your `HotelRoom` class. Do you implement an `equals` method?

Comment: You are not overriding `equals` and `hashCode` in `HotelRoom` therefore it is inheriting the default implementation from `Object` that uses `==`. As your actual and expected are not the same instance the test fails. A further note is that the `lowerRate` and `roomUnder` methods don't make sense - why would you pass _another_ `HotelRoom` to a `HotelRoom` - these methods should act on the instance itself - i.e. `this`. Or be `static.

Comment: How do you think `assertEquals` works?

Comment: It probably uses .equals() to compare two strings, so basically I need to override that .equals() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing something very basic. your `lowerRate` method returns an object of `HotelRoom` class and you are equalizing that object to a totally different object instance with the `assertEquals` method. Which is necessarily equalizing the objects reference (as you did not overriden `equals()` method). Because of being two different object, their references are different too and your assertion fails.

As you want to get equalize the objects based on your rate attribute then you need to override the equals method of class `HotelRoom` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){

    if(obj instanceof HotelRoom) {
       if( Math.abs(this.rateperNight - ((HotelRoom) obj).rateperNight) < .000001) {
            return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Only then your hotelrooms will be compared like your expectation.

See:

- [Object.equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [Object.hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.hashCode%28%29)

Comment: For some reason I got an error because of the @Override annotation saying "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". Why is this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in equals method and now I have edited and you can see now.

Comment: Yeah I included it into the HotelRoom class but it gives me that error and won't run/compile because of it. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to cast the `obj` to `HotelRoom`, like the edited answer!

Comment: That helped but the thing is now the o.rateperNight has an error because it can't find the symbol it says "cannot find symbol symbol: variable rateperNight location: variable o of type Obejct

Comment: You missed my second edit. In that I added the casting too... :P

Answer (score 3):

You should override the method `equals` in your `HotelRoom` class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    //return true if memberwise equal
}
```

Comment: Depending on your IDE it can do this for you.

Comment: Wrong, equals() tales Object as parameter